# Drag and drop in Angular 2.

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I know that there are many plugins for drag and drop in Angular 2 but some of them do not have  model uptades, some other do not have sorting functionality. What I need is to drag and drop with options above. One plugin seems fit

https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-dnd

But I have a problem after installation. When I import module I get error 'cannot find module' (folder exists)

```
import { NgxDnDModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-dnd'
```

So maybe do you have SIMPLE, SMALL, LITTLE library with functionalities I need?

Regards

Comment: you have to copy that module folder from 'node_modules' to your source directory, and then reference it using relative paths.

Comment: @pixelbits I tried with another library. Could you tell me what are DND_PROVIDERS and DND_DIRECTIVES in app.ts here? http://embed.plnkr.co/JbG8Si

Comment: where is the source where the dnd library is located in that plnkr?

Comment: https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd